# NodeJS UDP Server No sends after a while (leak?)

Tags: node.js, sockets, memory-leaks, udp

I have a pretty simple UDP server, using the build-in NodeJS dgram module, that listens to a port and, on receiving a UDP message, sends back a UDP response - very typical.

It works fine initially but after a while the responses never get back to the client - as if some leak (my leak?) has filled up a buffer.  No error messages are spat out by NodeJS.

I am only using one socket bound to one port.  I'm sending the responses back using this socket and to don't create any other sockets - this means I never close a socket.

Does anyone know why my program fails to get messages back to the client after a while (maybe after 50,000 requests/responses) ?

Thanks V Much!

Derek

The bare bones of my program: -

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
server.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
    console.log("Msg in from "+rinfo.address);
    dosomeworkwithmsg(msg, function(res) {
        server.send(res, 0, res.length, rinfo.port, rinfo.address, function(err, bytes) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error sending reply! "+err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Reply sent to client!");
            }
        });
    });
});
server.bind(2000);
```

Comment: Have you verified with something like Wireshark or tcpdump that your UDP packets aren't being sent?

Comment: No not yet - I'll check this.  I do know that if I stop the NodeJS program and re-start it then the responses instantly start going through again.  Derek